# Sign request urls for S3 objects using username and password Js SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I want to generate signed request URLs for accessing S3 objects using username and password instead of Access Key Id and Secret Access Key using Javascript SDK.Any way to do it?

Or there can be any way to get secret access key using username and password through JS SDK and then follow regular process to sign requests using that? But Amazon only allows secret access key to download once during creation.

They have also removed the support for IAM in the SDK.

Is it possible in some way? Any guidance is much appreciated.